# Type mismatch in scala with wildcards

Tags: java, scala, thrift

I have a piece of code from java that i am trying to implement in scala.

java code, works fine.

```
protected byte[] serialize(final TBase<?, ?> base) {
    try {
        return new TSerializer(new TCompactProtocol.Factory()).serialize(base);
        } catch (final TException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
}
```

scala code i am tyring to implement.

```
def serialize(base: TBase[_,_]): Array[Byte]={
try{
  return new TSerializer(new TCompactProtocol.Factory()).serialize(base)
}catch {
  case ex: TException => {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage())
  }
}
```

}

The compiler isnt giving me an error of `"type mismatch; found : org.apache.thrift.TBase[_$1,_$2] where type _$2, type _$1 required: 
 org.apache.thrift.TBase[_ <: org.apache.thrift.TBase[_, _], _ <: org.apache.thrift.TFieldIdEnum]"`

I looked around a lot and one of the suggestions was to use and some and none type. But not sure it is the right thing to do. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: I am not sure why it was downvoted. I think it is a valid question. Or I am missing something trivial.

Comment: It would be better if you posted the type constrains imposed by TBase or by the class containing the `serialize` method you are calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further information this answer is only a guess based on the error:

```
type mismatch; 
found : TBase[_$1,_$2] where type _$2, type _$1
required: TBase[_ <: TBase[_, _], _ <: TFieldIdEnum]
```

Constraining the type arguments as the error message suggested may fix the problem:

```
 def serialize(base: TBase[_ <: TBase[_,_] ,_ <: TFieldIdEnum])
```

It's hard to tell why this would be case, without seeing the signatures of the serialize methods and the TBase class. I can only speculate that the *java wildcards* brings the constraint already defined somewhere else, while the *scala existencials* doesn't, requiring that you state than explicitly.

Also, don't use the `return` keyword. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: thanks @pedrofurla you were right. This type constraint compiled but not sure it indeed does the serialization.                           1. Can you give me the concept behind how you came up with the constraints.

Comment: Isnt the wildcards supposed to be taking care of that.

Comment: Added more info as requested

Comment: I changed the return statement i created a var and assigned the bytes returned to it. I looked at various examples that do the same. Is there a reason it is done. I am looking at documentation. If i find a helpful link i will post it.